# How can I set in code page ID to be detect in google analytics?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I need to give any page in my website a unique ID to be detected in google analytics or firebase analytics.

I will explain:

First of all, I'm developing using React.js.

I have lots of pages (routes) on my website. for example:

https://mywebsite.com/website1

https://mywebsite.com/website2

https://mywebsite.com/website3

In someday, I will change the route of the page and I want to keep detect the analytics data from the history using API.

Because of that, I need to set a constant ID for each page to be detected no matter what the route is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a datalayer variable - if you kept the datalayer the same on the page (even if the URL is different) you can send the variable as a custom dimension to Google Analytics. You can then report on that custom dimension as if it was a page.